# Decode png-image stored as base64 in Android project

Tags: android, sqlite, base64

I have asked this before, but perhaps in a too inconcise way.

I have a SQLite database where a base64 string i stored in a BLOB column. I need to retreive this and show the image.

THis is how I try to fetch it:

```
 String[] blob = new String[4];
    startManagingCursor(c);  
     if (c.moveToFirst()){ 
            int i = 0; 
        do {blob[i] = c.getString(1);
         i++;} 

        while (c.moveToNext()); 
        c.close();

        String bild = blob[0];
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(bild, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        mImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

I have tried as well with:

```
             byte[] blob = new byte[4];
     startManagingCursor(c);  
     if (c.moveToFirst()){ 
            int i = 0; 
        do {
            blob = c.getBlob(1);
         i++;} 

        while (c.moveToNext()); 
        c.close();

        String bild = blob.toString();
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(bild, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        mImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

I have also tried to run one of the base64 strings in one of those decoder sites, and from there I can see it is a png-file.

BUt still, in the Android project I only get NULL reults. What am I missing? I had some recent problems with a misinterpretaion of utf-8 as macroman. Can there be a misinterpretation of my base64 code string as well?

Many thanks if someone could point me the right direction!

Comment: Have you checked the content of the blob[] array and compared it to the values in the database table?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that the value returned is the same as in the database. I have also tried to fetch it as byte[] with c.getBlob(0), convert it to a string and print it. I have decoded it in one of those online decoder and there i get a textstring that says it is a png-image. But I just don't seem to be able to decode it in ANdroid.